# Unable to Install Apps from on Samsung Phone

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, samsung

A friend of mine gave me here phone to install an application from Play store because she could not do on her own. It was a Galaxy J1 mini phone and I thought it would not take long to install the app which was 5 MB. The app downloaded up to 99% and when it was time to install it failed to continue. Later I tried the second and third time but it was all in vain.

I decided to send the app from another Android phone using but it didn't have flash share so I used Bluetooth. Funny enough the apk on the phone appeared unrecognized at all. In short the phone didn't have an installer app or it had been corrupted by a virus or got deleted by mistake. How is it that such an important system app could go missing on a phone? How can I solve such an issue next time?

Comment: Well if the system installer isn't present then why not consider running through with an apk installer?

Comment: But thinking about it you can't install an apk installer. Then I'd recommend I'm using ADB code to install the apk installer from your computer.